# vmime connects but is not visible in the project

Tags: c++, gcc, vmime

I need to include the vmime library in a project. I am using macOS. I cloned the repository from the github, compiled the library, there are no problems with this. The headers are in /usr/local/include/vmime and the dylib file is in /usr/local/lib. My cmake looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(MyProject)

find_package(vmime REQUIRED)
include_directories(${VMIME_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${VMIME_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${VMIME_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(MyProject main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(MyProject ${VMIME_LIBRARIES})
```

He, as far as I understand, finds the library and connects it, since cmake is built without errors

However, the header is not connected, it is always red and cannot determine the library

```
#include <vmime/vmime.hpp>
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Does the build succeed?

Comment: Yes, the build goes without problems. Moreover, in the examples that are in the library itself, everything works fine, but the cmakelist there is too complex and is built from several files, so I won't be able to use it in my project

Comment: If the build succeeds then maybe it's problem of your editor that it isn't able to detect it properly.

Comment: I use CLion, it never had such problems